# How do I call mpmovieplayer from applicationwillresignactive in ppdelegate?

Tags: audio-streaming, mpmovieplayer, audiosession

I'm using `mpmovieplayer` to play an audio stream. I'm having trouble with handling intruptions e.g when a call is received. My player is declared in `viewcontroller` and I beleive I need to do something in `applicationdidresignactive` in my `appdelegate` right? How do I do that if my `appdelegate` isn't aware of my `moviePlayer`? I'm new to iPhone development so I'm learning as I go and enjoying it :)

Here is what I'm doing in `viewcontroller`

```
-(IBAction)play1MButton:(id)sender{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(moviePlayerStatus:) 
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
        object:nil];

    NSString *url = @"http://22.22.22.22:8000/listen.pls";

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
        initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
        selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) 
        name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
        object:nil];
}

-(void) moviePlayerStatus:(NSNotification*)notification {

    //MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = notification.object;
    MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;

    if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward");
    } else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward) {
        NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward");
    }
}

- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ([moviePlayer loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                        name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                           object:moviePlayer];

        [moviePlayer play];

        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    }

}
```

and in `appdelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
    if (setCategoryError) {

    }

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
    if (activationError) { 
    }
```

I can catch the errors, but how do I use the player from appdelegate?

Comment: Anyone? I still cant figure it out!! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the class where your MPMoviePlayerController is. Use this code in the AppDelegate.h "`import "YourClassNameWithThePlayer.h"`".
Maybe that can help. I am also new at this, and I hope you consider it.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did more reading about this and i think i've worked out what i need to do...i'm still exploring ios xcode.....